# Should I make partition when setting up a RAID-1?

Tags: raid, multi-boot

If I want to do RAID-1, and I also want to boot several different OSes (Windows 7, Linux) for example, should I perform the following steps?

1. Create RAID-1 Mirror from BIOS.
2. Use GParted to create several partitions.
     <sub>(I believe under GParted, I will see two disks, under which one should I create the partitions then?)</sub>
3. Install Windows and then Ubuntu?

Or is it better to create RAID-1 and install RAID-1 on the whole disk first, then resize the partition later for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Do a RAID1 mirror in the BIOS.  That is OS independent.

You can use GParted, or another tool to make partitions, but it will only see the one RAID volume.  Again, since the RAID is in BIOS, Linux - which GParted runs on, doesnt see both disks, just the RAID disk presented by BIOS.

Then install your OSs as necessary.

Comment: hi. thanks for the response. actually, it does, for a strange reason. It shows me  "dev/mapper/raid1,   dev/sda and dev/sdb"  what should i do? thanks!